# Using python to dynamically divine the contents of a CORBA (omniORB) interface

Tags: python, introspection, corba

I'm trying to write a self-maintaining test tool that can be used from the command line against a server via CORBA (omniORB).  To start, I'd be happy with a tool that could describe the interface(s) that the server implements (e.g., essentially regenerating the IDL that defined the interfaces to begin with). From there, I'd grow it into something that could accept parameters, make the CORBA call, and print the results.

I know that python has introspection that should make it possible to not have to write (much) code every time an argument changes or a new method is added.  But I don't understand enough of the python binding for omniORB (or enough python) to know how to do this easily (or whether an infrastructure already exists to do this).

I've inherited some code that I'm trying to morph into my test tool.  The problem is that I don't know how much is something that is stock omniORB python support and how much is homebrew.

From what I'm seeing, it looks like an omniORB CORBA interface appears in python as a class (that part seems likely standard).  The methods of said interface appear as members of this class--they are each tuples with naming that appears to be the method name from the IDL prefixed with `_d_`.  The input parameters for a given interface method are described by said method's first tuple element; the second element describes the return values.  Each element is another tuple of tuples, with each describing a successive parameter.

I'm hoping this reflects the implementation of omniORBpy. Assuming that it does, are there well-defined routines for interrogating/manipulating these interface class objects?

Comment: So what you are asking is, how can I learn the interfaces that a server supports without knowing the IDL in advance? CORBA is a huge standard, and I think they support a dynamic invocation and dispatch mechanism, but I have not used it and don't know if omniORB supports it.

Comment: Sort of but not exactly.  I have the IDL; I just don't want to have to update a test tool every time the IDL changes.  Instead, I'd like to write the test tool in such a way that it is self-maintaining --so that it figures out what methods are available (and what the parameters of the methods are).

Comment: The methods available are documented in the IDL. If the IDL changes, you (and the tool) know, what the changes are. What shall the tool do? Using an old IDL to figure out what's new?

Comment: The existence of the interface is well defined.  It's the methods and parameters that are evolving.  As mentioned, there appears to be a sort of convention for how methods (and their parameters) are exposed to python (at least in omniORB).  I'm trying to find something that either defines the convention or, even better, implements an introspection-based framework around it-- that, say, lets a tool be agnostic to any changes to IDL and instead presents the interface in a way that can be traversed (e.g., print out a call list of methods and parameters like javadoc).

Comment: I removed my answer. I found some apparently old documentation that said that omniORB supported DII, but there is no sign of that in the latest documentation. If DII was supported, that would probably be the best way to go. Failing that, I don't have any good answers for you. Good luck.